# Активировал учётную запись Администратор,теперь не могу открывать файлы от админа,просит пароль который я в принципе не давал

Tags: windows

Как мне это всё дело сбросить или поставить новый пароль

Answer (score 0):

Если есть еще учетная запись с правами Администратора, то

1. ПКМ по пуску
2. Управление Компьютером > Служебные программы >  Локальные пользователи и группы > Пользователи
3. ПКМ по УЗ Администратор
4. Свойства
5. поставить галку "Отключить"
6. Применить

Либо если нужно изменить пароль Администратора то
1-3 пункт выше
4. Задать пароль
5. Продолжить
6. ввести пароль и повторить и нажать ок